# How to create a eCommerce site products slideshow using views

Tags: views

Environment: D8 with commerce module.

I am working on a eCommerce website. I created a view to display the products as unformatted list. How can I change it to a slider/slideshow view? Each slide should have 5 products info. Each product of the slideshow should contain title, list price, catalog image, short desc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Current view:

[image]

How the view should look like with the slider:

[image]

How can I modify the view to make it a slideshow like the above design?

--

Update 1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use view_slideshow module

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

Before installing read README.html file present in the module. you can achieve the required output.

If you need more customization in the slider, you can use

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/  also...if above one does not satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Please see the update 1. I installed views slideshow module. But I am not sure how to make it work.